# SoapServerException on Lists.GetListItems()

Tags: 2010, web-services, exception-handling

I'm trying to retrieve list items for my "Country" list through web services.

This is my list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/158MI.png

& this is my code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace SPwebservices
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SPlistservices.Lists client = new SPlistservices.Lists();
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("****", "******");

            System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            XmlNode ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
            XmlNode viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
            XmlNode ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");

            viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\" />" +
                "<FieldRef Name=\"AgentName\" />" +
                "<FieldRef Name=\"AgentNumber\" />";


            XmlNode listItems = client.GetListItems("Country", null, ndQuery, viewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);

                foreach (XmlNode node in listItems)
                    if (node.Name == "rs:data")
                        for (int f = 0; f < node.ChildNodes.Count; f++)
                        {
                            if (node.ChildNodes[f].Name == "z:row")
                            {
                                string title = node.ChildNodes[f].Attributes["ows_Title"].Value;
                                string agentName = node.ChildNodes[f].Attributes["ows_AgentName"].Value;
                                string agentNumber = node.ChildNodes[f].Attributes["ows_AgentNumber"].Value;

                                Console.WriteLine(title + " " + agentName + " " + agentNumber);
                            }
                        }   
                 Console.ReadKey(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get this exception:

> Exception of type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.SoapServer.SoapServerException' was thrown.
>
> "List does not exist.The page you selected contains a list that does
>   not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."

pointing at:

```
XmlNode listItems = client.GetListItems("Country", null, ndQuery, viewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
```

Does anyone have a clue, what's wrong?

I got this from a tutorial so its very difficult for me to debug it..

Comment: did you check with fiddler and/or soapUI? maybe you have to many items

Comment: if you see this error may be uncurrect list or view ID

Comment: Any you get a final solution? For me, the signature for `GetListItems` method is

  `public System.Xml.Linq.XElement GetListItems(string listName, string viewName, System.Xml.Linq.XElement query, System.Xml.Linq.XElement viewFields, string rowLimit, System.Xml.Linq.XElement queryOptions, string webID)` 

It use `XElement`, not `XmlElement` neither `XmlNOde`.

And I get the same error about it.

Answer (score 1):

Webservice reference points to the root site. And I am guessing list does not exists in root site. Is your list URL looks like following:

```
http://yoursite/WEB/lists/Country
```

If yes then above code is searching list in 'yoursite' and not in 'WEB'
Check this link: [Accessing subsites' lists via the MOSS 2007 Lists.asmx web service](http://brainof-dave.blogspot.com/2008/07/accessing-subsites-lists-via-moss-2007.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Xml.XmlNode nodes = myservice.GetListItems(listName, viewName, query, viewFields, rowLimit, null, null);
```

check the above line and check this link may it helps you.

http://sarangasl.blogspot.in/2009/12/sharepoint-list-web-service.html

Comment: Thanks for this! Its a nice example. I'll give it try separately and see if the exception persists over there..

Comment: Sorry @Robert Kaucher, I think I dropped this after a couple of days trying. Its been a while though..

Answer (score 0):

Please, Check if the WebReference that you created has the property "Web Reference URL" something like: http://topLevelSite.yourdomain.br/sites/yourTestSite/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx.

In my case, i was reference it for a wrong URL. After i just right it, the excpetion is gone way.